# How to remove markings from laundry sink

Tags: cleaning, sink

The laundry sink plug was blocked at one stage and did not drain properly. After the plug was unblocked there were markings which were left on the sides of the sink - see the image below:

[image: laundry tub with markings]

These markings appear to be a stain, rather than material stuck to the surface. Any suggestions on how to clean it? I have tried bleach but that had little effect.

Comment: Is that a stain or material actually stuck to the surface? If the latter how about a green scrub pad with the rough surface?

Comment: It appears to be a stain, rather than material stuck to the surface.

Comment: Did you try scrubbing bubbles?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem after using a drain cleaner for a bathtub and for a sink.  I used Glass Plus, a multi-purpose cleaner found in the window-cleaner aisle of the grocery or big-box stores.  I sprayed it on, let it sit, and scrubbed it off with a sponge.  It is non-toxic.

After finding that it cleaned a litter box and neutralized the urine smell, I sent the bottle and a roll of paper towels with the 7-year old boy to clean his toilet splatters!  Since the success if that, we have learned that we can put half water and half Glass Plus in the spray bottle, and we use it routinely to clean the outside of their toilet and the floor around it as well as their bathroom sink and tub.  Adding the water is just an economical way of making the Glass Plus last longer.  It is not expensive anyway, only about $4 a bottle, but there are 5 toilets in this house, with 6 people, 3 of whom are boys under the age of 13, who do not have specific aim when using the bathroom.  It is important that we use that spray to disinfect as well as to neutralize the smell of urine.  All our boys can clean their own bathrooms, and get sent to do it whenever they need to behave better.

Answer (score 0):

When bleach doesn't do it, vinegar, citric acid or one of those sulphamic or hydroxyacetic acid toilet bowl cleaners are the usual next step.
100 grams citric, or a cup of the other acids in a sink full of water, and let it sit several hours. Scrub with a toilet brush.

Answer (score 0):

try ZUD, works on everything that I've had trouble cleaning. Contains oxalic acid which can cause some skin irritation.